# How to download the audio from my own YouTube videos that are on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I have some YouTube videos on YouTube. Is there a way to just get the audio from them?

I am able to get the mp4 format video download. If I can't get the audio directly, how could I get the audio-only file from the mp4 file?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions about [Web sites out of your control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are off-topic for this site, so as with your other questions about YouTube, they should be asked on [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). However be sure to read their FAQ's as recommendations are generally considered off-topic for Stack Exchange sites since they can result in spam and self-promotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this site: http://www.clipconverter.cc/

Input the youtube url for the video, then choose the format.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question has already be answered, but if you'd like a software solution you can download this: http://download.cnet.com/Free-YouTube-Downloader/3000-2071_4-75219434.html?tag=mncol;7

It has a download audio only option. The only problem I've had with it is if you use the "MP4 (no conversion)" option it doesn't add the .mp4 extension so you'll have to do that manually.

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with this software?

Comment: No. I just found it years ago and use it for downloading videos for my youth group since our church doesn't have internet.